# Does Strionic Resonator cause Medomai, the Ageless to let me take 3 turns upon hitting someone?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

We are playing commander and [Medomai the Ageless](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMedomai%20the%20Ageless%5d) is my commander. If I use [Strionic Resonator](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStrionic%20Resonator%5d) on the triggered ability to take an extra turn, it adds two instances of take an extra turn so it should give me 3 turns right?

Comment: a little confusing how it's worded, taking 3 turns rather than taking 2 extra turns.

Comment: I interpreted the question as asking if you get to take three extra turns - if that's not what you meant, might want to edit the question for clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, extra turns can stack in this way.

> 500.7. Some effects can give a player extra turns. They do this by adding the turns directly after the specified turn. If a player is given multiple extra turns, the extra turns are added one at a time. If multiple players are given extra turns, the extra turns are added one at a time, in APNAP order (see rule 101.4). The most recently created turn will be taken first.

Answer (score 5):

**Yes, Medomai's ability is triggered and can be copied with Strionic Resonator, giving you 2 extra turns.**

> 603.1. Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[When/Whenever/At] [trigger condition or event], [effect]. [Instructions (if any).]”

Comment: Thanks i was confused as to whether the turns add on to one another giving multiple turns or just 1 turn